# Submit form to another domain

Tags: ajax, post

I need to access the result of submitting a form to a website.

There is a web site where you complete a form and it posts the information using ajax and then tells you if you have their service in the are or not.

I'd like to be able to do this from my web page, which means posting the information required by the form to their server and getting the result.

The problem is I get "403 Forbidden", I think it's because the "Origin" being a different domain.

Is there anyway that I can the response from the server on my website? 
I thought about php_curl (used once with google docs api) but would like to know what you guys think it's the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxying the request through your own web server that is available in the same domain as the webpage making the ajax call is the only clean way.

Comment: but can't you simply set the form fields automatically and then download the response? Or download the form and then set the fields and get the response?
For what I understood from your answer, my server needs to have the same domain as the one with the form, right?

Comment: The form post is to a different domain, the response to it will replace the current page, basically it is not an ajax request, and if you try to POST through ajax then the browser will block you from doing that.

Comment: So there isn't anyway to get the response from another domain if I can't control it?

Comment: Correct unless you do what I my answer says, proxy the request through your own webserver.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance but how can I do that? And what does it mean exactly? Oh and thanks for the help :)

Comment: Simple, the action of the form post  should point to your web server, which actually makes the request to the actual server waits for the response and forwards it to the browser.

Comment: Many many thanks for the you time...I'll be trying that. Thanks again